# How to replace each third comma with a newline?

Tags: regex, notepad++, newline

I have a text file full of coordinates, but it is not looking organize. How do you change from `1.0f, 3.0f, 2.0f, 4.0f, 1.0f, 2.0f, 4.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f` to

```
1.0f, 3.0f, 2.0f,
4.0f, 1.0f, 2.0f,
4.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f
```

is it possible to do that from notepad++?

Comment: Yes, that is possible.

Answer (score 3):

For a start, try to replace `(([^,]*,){3})` with `\1\n`. This will match three occurrences of non-comma characters followed by a comma.

```
1.0f, 3.0f, 2.0f,
 4.0f, 1.0f, 2.0f,
 4.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f
```

You will still have to deal with the extra whitespace at the beginning of each line, but it should point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 2):

One approach is to match a sequence that has three commas separated by zero or more non-commas, capture it, and replace with the captured data followed by `\n`:

```
Find what:     (([^,]*,){3}\s*)
Replace with:  \1\n
```

`\1` represents the content captured by the regular expression. `\n` represents the new line character, which is appended to each line.